# There is an issue where infinite scrolling is not reflected on the first render

Tags: reactjs, intersection-observer

```
import { Button, Image, Modal, Popover } from "antd";
import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

const ImageViewer = ({
  prevImg,
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [visibleImages, setVisibleImages] = useState(12);


  const observerRef = useRef(null);

  const [initialSetup, setInitialSetup] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const observerOptions = {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: "0px",
      threshold: 0.5
    };

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
      entries.forEach((entry) => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
          setVisibleImages((prevVisibleImages) => prevVisibleImages + 12);
        }
      });
    }, observerOptions);

    if (observerRef.current) {
      observer.observe(observerRef.current);
    }

    if (initialSetup) {
      setInitialSetup(false);
    }

    return () => {
      if (observerRef.current) {
        observer.unobserve(observerRef.current);
      }
    };
  }, [prevImg]);

  return (
    <Modal
      title={t("Image Inspection")}
      centered
      footer={[]}
    >
      {prevImg.length > 0 && (
        <div className="imagecontainer">
          <ButtonContainer>
            {Array.from({ length: Math.min(visibleImages, prevImg.length) }, (_, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <Button type="primary" key={`button-${index}`} danger>
                  Remove
                </Button>
              </div>
            ))}
          </ButtonContainer>

          <ImageGrid>
            {prevImg.slice(0, visibleImages).map((img, index) => (
              <Popover key={index}>
                <Image key={index} src={img} preview={{ src: img }} alt={uuidv4()} style={{ objectFit: "contain" }}S />
              </Popover>
            ))}
            <div ref={observerRef} style={{ height: "10px" }} />
          </ImageGrid>
        </div>
      )}
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default ImageViewer;
```

[image]

This photo shows the first render without the infinite scroll reflected.

I'm using the InterSection Observer API to implement infinite scrolling, and when I write the code as above, the infinite scrolling is not applied, but when I re-render once, the infinite scrolling is reflected.

Even if I put `visibleImages` or `initialSetup` in addition to `prevImg` in the dependency array of useEffect, the infinite scroll is still not reflected in the first render, and I have to re-render.

I would like to know what could be the cause.